# Passing argument to method nested in the dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Link to repo: https://github.com/jsarnowski96/pysql-console

I'm currently working on Data Analysis method in my program. The problem I've encountered and which shouldn't really happen since I used this solution previously (custom built-in commands dictionary) is in the passing optional arguments to the method calls inside the `allowed_params` dictionary:

```
def DataAnalysis(fileName = "", param = "", num=""):
try:
    filePath = ""
    if settings.global_config_array["sourceCsvFile"] != None:
        filePath = settings.global_config_array["sourceCsvFile"]
    if fileName == "" and settings.global_config_array["sourceCsvFile"] == None:
        print("You did not enter CSV file name.")
        while fileName == "" or not os.path.exists(fileName):
            fileName = str(input("Please insert the CSV filename for data analysis: "))
            if fileName == "":
                print("You did not enter the filename.\n")
            else:
                filePath = "exports/" + fileName + ".csv"
                settings.global_config_array["sourceCsvFile"] = filePath
            if os.path.exists(filePath):
                print("File " + fileName + ".csv found.\n")
                if param == "":
                    param = str(input("Insert the parameter: "))
                break
            else:
                print("File " + fileName + ".csv not found.\n")
    elif fileName == "" and settings.global_config_array["sourceCsvFile"] != None:
        if os.path.exists(settings.global_config_array["sourceCsvFile"]):
            filePath = settings.global_config_array["sourceCsvFile"]
    elif fileName != "" and settings.global_config_array["sourceCsvFile"] != None:
        filePath = "exports/" + fileName + ".csv"
        if os.path.exists(filePath):
            print("File " + fileName + ".csv found.\n")
            settings.global_config_array["sourceCsvFile"] = filePath  
        else:
            if settings.global_config_array["sourceCsvFile"] != None:
                filePath = settings.global_config_array["sourceCsvFile"]
                if os.path.exists(filePath):
                    num = param
                    param = fileName
    elif fileName != "" and settings.global_config_array["sourceCsvFile"] == None:
        filePath = "exports/" + fileName + ".csv"
        if os.path.exists(filePath):
            print("File " + fileName + ".csv found.\n")
            settings.global_config_array["sourceCsvFile"] = filePath      
    def switch_params(param, num):
        result = None
        dataframe = pd.read_csv(filePath)
        columns = []
        for col in dataframe.columns:
            columns.append(col)
        allowed_params = {
            "describe": dataframe.describe,
            "info": dataframe.info,
            "explode": dataframe.explode,
            "hist": dataframe.hist,
            "cols": dataframe.columns,
            "head": dataframe.head, # the problem begins here
            "summary": smf.ols,
            "free": None
        }

        if param in allowed_params and param == "free":
            settings.global_config_array["sourceCsvFile"] = allowed_params["free"]
        elif param in allowed_params and param != "free":
            result = allowed_params[param]
            print(result,"\n")
        elif param in allowed_params and param == "head":
            if num == "":
                num = input("Insert the amount of rows to display in 'head' statement: ")
            while num > dataframe.size:
                num = input("Provided number exceeds the size of the dataframe. Please try again: ")
            result = allowed_params[param](int(num)) # and the proper execution is here
            print(result)
        elif param in allowed_params and param == "summary":
            result = allowed_params[param](columns, dataframe).fit()
            print(result.summary())
        elif param in allowed_params:
            result = allowed_params[param]()
            print(result)
        elif param == "":
            result = allowed_params["describe"]
            print(result,"\n")
        else:
            print("Incorrect parameter inserted.\n")
    switch_params(param, num)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\nTerminating command...\n")
except IOError:
    print("File " + fileName + ".csv " + "does not exist.\n")
except Exception as e:
    print(e,"\n")
except pyodbc.Error as e:
    sqlstate = e.args[0]
    if sqlstate == "42S02":
        print("Error " + e.args[0] + ": Cannot create a temporal table - referenced object does not exist in the selected database.\n")
    else:
        print("Error",e.args[0] + ":\n",e,"\n")
```

Using this kind of indirect method execution calls worked like a charm in case of my custom built-in commands, but it doesn't seem to work at all with `pandas.DataFrame` objects, or it's at least really badly supported.

I can see two major problems:
- if I decide to put `dataframe.head(int(num))` directly inside the dictionary, it will be executed every time I use `da` command and this is exactly what I want to avoid at all cost.
- if I leave it as it is, the `head` method works, but it ignores the `num` parameter, so it always displays full content of target CSV file.

Comment: What is the exact problem with running dataframe.head(10) everytime you run the program?

Comment: I want to pass that number as an optional argument every time I run this method. But placing it directly in dictionary causes it to execute no matter what, and using the above method of assigning dataframe.head(int(num)) to 'result' variable doesn't seem to work at all - the value is being read by the pandas, but it isn't used, so the solution of using
result = allowed_params[param](int(num)) is inefficient at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Does this (simplified example) do the trick?

```
def switch_params(param, num=None):
    dataframe = pd.read_csv(filePath)
    if num:
        head = dataframe.head(num)
    else:
        head = None
    allowed_params = {
        "describe": dataframe.describe,
        "head": head
    }
```

Comment: honestly, this is one of the ideas/workarounds I was thinking about. guess that the best solution will be to remove that method call from the dict and just execute it directly. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out that the small hack was necessary in order to get that fully operational.

- removed `head` field from the `allowed_params` dictionary
- changed if statement to check if param is only equal `head`, without checking if it exists in `allowed_params`
- `dataframe.head(int(num))` is called directly in `result` variable

This way I was able to get the expected result without sacrificing too much of the original concept/implementation.

```
            elif param == "head":
            if num == "":
                num = input("Insert the amount of rows to display in 'head' statement: ")
            while int(num) > len(dataframe) or int(num) == 0:
                if int(num) == 0:
                    num = input("Number 0 is not allowed. Please try again: ")
                else:
                    num = input("Provided number exceeds the size of the dataframe. Please try again: ")
            result = dataframe.head(int(num))
            print("\n",result,"\n")
```

[image]